# PickerView not showing any values

Tags: ios, xcode, swift

Here is the code that I used:

```
// PickerView Functions

func numberOfComponentsInPickerView(pickerView: UIPickerView) -> Int {
    return 1
}

//
func pickerView(pickerView: UIPickerView, numberOfRowsInComponent
    component: Int) -> Int {

            return categoryArray.count // also tried with 5 or other numbers...

}

func pickerView(pickerView: UIPickerView, viewForRow row: Int,
    forComponent component: Int, reusingView view: UIView!) -> UIView {
        var lab : UILabel!
            if let label = view as? UILabel {
                lab = label
            } else {
                lab = UILabel()
            }
            lab.text = categoryArray[row] // also tried with text like "some test"
            lab.backgroundColor = UIColor.clearColor()
            lab.sizeToFit()
            return lab
}

func pickerView(pickerView: UIPickerView, didSelectRow row: Int, inComponent component: Int) {
       self.categoryLabel.text = categoryArray[row]
}
```

The `PickerViewDelegate` is set and all outlets are created and hooked up...
If I run this code, it doesn't return any values from the `categoryArray` although this is already filled with values. I also tried to manually fill the Picker but that also didn't work. What could be the reason, any ideas?

Comment: Perhaps your frame is 0,0,0,0? Can you check the frame of the picker and make sure it actually has size?

Comment: Add a break point to see whether will jump into the delegate. And had you  assign delegate to somewhere(self)?

Comment: please add that as an answer and accept it, so this doesn't show up as unanswered

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks guys for the comments, I found the issue... I forgot to set the delegate to self in the viewDidLoad, I only implemented the delegate class, sure that can't work ;-)

Answer (score 1):

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    picker.delegate = self
    picker.dataSource = self
    picker.tag = 1
}
```

Hope it works.